# Scroll issue in custom layout for listview item

Tags: android, android-widget

I am using a custom layout for eack item in listview. Each item looks like

```
--------------------
Image|filename|image
     |fileinfo|
--------------------
```

I used textview for displaying filename and fileinfo. To have a horizontal scroll in filename textview if content exceeds length, i surround it with horizontalscrollview. But listitem click is not working. here is my lite item layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="8dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/file" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.17"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fileName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </HorizontalScrollView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fileInfo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="10dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/navIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout> <!-- $Id:$ -->
```

This is my item click code

```
 private static FileListAdapter fileListAdapter; //extends from array adapter
 private static ListView fileListView;
fileListAdapter =new FileListAdapter(EditorActivity.getActivity(), R.layout.listview_item_row, localFiles);     
        fileListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
            {

            }
        });
```

Please correct me.

Answer (score 0):

Though I am not sure , I think you should enclose whole list view in HOraizontal view rather a single scrollview.

For your problem it is better to use edittext view rather using Text view .
just keep in mind your edit text will be non foucsable and non editable and background will be transperent

Convert this section in

> ```
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/fileName"
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>                 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>                 android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
>                 android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
>                 android:gravity="center_vertical"
>                 android:textColor="@color/white"
>                 android:textSize="15dp"
>                 android:textStyle="bold" />
>         </HorizontalScrollView>
> ```

```
<EditText
                    android:id="@+id/fileName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" 


android:background="#00000000"
 android:focusable="false"
  android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
  android:editable="false"
  android:clickable="false"
  android:scrollHorizontally="true"
  android:singleLine="true"

                    />
```